Mapping left and right mouse clicks to keyboard button on linux
My laptop (linux) is getting a bit worn out and the buttons on my touchpad tend to get stuck, so I'm trying to map the left- and right-click to a keyboard key using xmodmap.
As far as I understand the command
xmodmap -e "keycode 94 = Pointer_Left Pointer_Right"

should make it such that when I press key 94 it left-clicks and when I press Shift+key 94 it right-clicks. (Which is what I want)
However when I try it only the left-click (without shift) works and the right-click (with shift) does nothing.
I get the exact same result when I do
xmodmap -e "keycode 94 = Pointer_Right Pointer_Left"

i.e. without shift results in left-click and with shift does nothing.
When I substitute Pointer_Left and Pointer_Right for other keysyms (such as a and b) it works fine.
Am I doing something wrong?
Also what's the keysym for middle-click?

Pointer_Button1 0xfee9, Pointer_Button2 0xfeea, Pointer_Button3 0xfeeb, Pointer_Button4 0xfeec, Pointer_Button5 0xfeed  I don't really know what these do... MouseKeys_Enable 0xfe76, MouseKeys_Accel_Enable 0xfe77 Key List
